# The .nvmrc file is not read

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am creating a project in Node JS and I want to use a specific version of the ones I have installed for this project.

These are the steps I have followed:

```
node -v

v10.20.1

node list

     14.17.0
   * 10.20.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

node -v> .nvmrc

cat. \. nvmrc

v14.17.0
```

**My problem** is when using mvn use to use the version defined in the .nvmrc file:

```
nvm use

.0.0
node v.0.0 (64-bit) is not installed.
```

Why doesn't it read the version of the file?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @eol I am using windows 10

Answer (score 7):

It seems that on Windows `.nvmrc` support is limited - see this github issue for more details: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/16

Note that if you're using git-bash for windows, you can use the following command as a workaround:

```
$ nvm use `cat .nvmrc`
```

Comment: This returns the same problem as before: `cat.0.0
node vcat.0.0 (64-bit) is not installed.`

Comment: Are you sure you're using *git-bash*? Works fine for me this way.

Comment: Ok if using the git bash console works fine. But the general version is also changed? Why is that version not fixed only for that project?

Comment: I think the .nvmrc is generally not working/supported as it is on linux. See the author's comment: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/16#issuecomment-431874527

Comment: Ok, so I'll delete that file

Comment: I was wondering why I was not able to use `.nvmrc`. Turns out a windows issue

Answer (score 0):

The `.nvmrc` file does not work on Windows. I am using it like this from `Visual Studio Code` cmd terminal on `Windows 10`:

```
nvm install 18.7.0
nvm use 18.7.0
```